# LINQ OrderBy is not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, linq-to-objects

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OrderByElementSubelement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Place> places = new List<Place>();
            places.Add(new Place { Address = "Fifth Street", Score = 29, Houses = new List<House> { new House { Owner = "Mike", Score = 32 }, new House { Owner = "Bobby", Score = 3 } } });
            places.Add(new Place { Address = "Sixth Street", Score = 29, Houses = new List<House> { new House { Owner = "Mike", Score = 42 }, new House { Owner = "Ted", Score = 45 } } });
            places.Add(new Place { Address = "Seventh Street", Score = 29, Houses = new List<House> { new House { Owner = "Randy", Score = 84 }, new House { Owner = "William", Score = 1 } } });
            var placesWithMikesHouseOrderedByMikesHouseScore = places.Where(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Count() > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Select(z => z.Score)).ToList();
        }

        public class Place
        {
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public int Score { get; set; }
            public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
        }

        public class House
        {
            public string Owner { get; set; }
            public int Score { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

I am trying to query for places with Mike's house ordered by Mike's house's score in that place (you can see from above the idea). A place has a list of houses. **Important: You can assume that no individual Owner can own more than one house per place!**

Why does it want an object to implement IComparable here, and how can I make this query work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `OrderBy` function returns a collection, not a single element:

```
OrderBy(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Select(z => z.Score))
```

You would need to constrain it to just the Score, not an `IEnumerable<double>` (if `Score` is a `double`), ie:

```
OrderBy(x => x.Houses.First(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Score)
```

Note that this would throw if there wasn't a house with `"Mike"` as the owner, however, your first filter should handle that.

Answer (score 3):

Here I have snipped out just your `OrderBy` clause:

```
OrderBy(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Select(z => z.Score))
```

Your problem is that even though `x.Houses.Where().Select()` only has one element it still returns an `IEnumerable` which doesn't implement `IComparable` and isn't valid for ordering.

You want to only select the first item in that collection so you have a few options:

```
OrderBy(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Select(z => z.Score).Single())
OrderBy(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Select(z => z.Score).SingleOrDefault())
OrderBy(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Select(z => z.Score).First())
OrderBy(x => x.Houses.Where(y => y.Owner == "Mike").Select(z => z.Score).FirstOrDefault())
```

Each of these has different behavior **if** the collection contains multiple elements and **the same** behavior if it contains exactly one element.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Reed's answer

```
var foo = places.Where(p => p.Houses.Any(h => h.Owner == "Mike"))
                .OrderBy(p => p.Houses.Single(h => h.Owner == "Mike").Score);
```

(Tangent: Your first **Where().Count > 0** should probably just be an **Any()**)

As other answers have pointed out, the OrderBy needs to be provided just the score. Alternatively, you could [make your House class implement IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow you to just sort houses directly.

If you your requirement that Mike only owns one house in a place is removed, you may want to have the BEST score for all of Mike's houses in a place, in which case you could adjust to something like the following...

```
.OrderBy(p => p.Houses.Where(h => h.Owner == "Mike").Max(h => h.Score));
```

(Logic about OrderBy vs OrderByDescending and Max vs Min not really considered)